# Way to be notified when the software keyboard is showing/hiding?

Tags: android

Is there a way to be notified when the keyboard is about to show, or has shown?  The following events would be great:

keyboardWillShow
keyboardDidShow
keyboardWillHide
keyboardDidHide

Comment: Possibly helpful link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to override the `View`'s `onSizeChanged()` method.  See this thread on the Android Developers group:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9d1681a01f05e782

Answer (score 0):

As MatrixFrog mentioned you can use the Activity's `onCofigurationChanged` method. With that you have keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide.

To get the other two you can try using one of the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)'s methods but I don't think a callback like that exists.